# Google Analytics API conversions

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

How to acquire certain type of conversion from GA PHP API (PostClick/PostView/LastClick)?

[Multi-Channel Funnels](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference#introduction) seem like a solution somehow, but there is only brief documentation for Java.

What I have tried.

```
$ga = new gapi('ivory-analyst-5555555@appspot.gserviceaccount.com','pages/key.p12'); 
$ga->requestReportData($qq->data[0]['Credentials'],array('campaign'), array('adClicks','impressions','CTR','CPC','adCost','costPerConversion','transac‌​tions','transactionRevenue'),'','',$from,$to);
```

Comment: welcome to stack http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you will need to show us what you have tried before we can help you with any problems you are having with it.

Comment: The point is I haven't tried anything, because I don't know what to try (obviously). Only thing I've done yet is this:
`code 
$ga = new gapi('ivory-analyst-5555555@appspot.gserviceaccount.com','pages/key.p12');
   $ga->requestReportData($qq->data[0]['Credentials'],array('campaign'), array('adClicks','impressions','CTR','CPC','adCost','costPerConversion','transactions','transactionRevenue'),'','',$from,$to);
` ,which tells me anything about origin of conversions.

Comment: do you want to do this In Java or PHP then?

Comment: In PHP. At least I need to get the data to PHP...

Comment: I would like to sugest you go and play with this tool https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.mcf.get   If you can actually get it to spit out the data you are looking for I can help you get it working with PHP.   Personally I have yet to get any data that makes sense out of the MCF API sadly.

Comment: Thank you a lot! What is that Table ID? In previous cases I used account ID, which is apparently invalid for this case.

Comment: check the documentation or I will try it in the morning.

Comment: Ok, I have found it somewhere. MCF does not seem to be very helpful...
Are you aware of any other way to get PostClick/PostView/LastClick conversion data? Is it even possible? (I don't really know as I am new to the Ad APIs)